# How long should I expect to spend at the Smithsonian National Museum of Natural History?

Tags: museums, washington-dc

I have the good fortune to have an extra day on a business trip in Washington DC. 
I've decided I'd like to spend that day at the Smithsonian National Museum of Natural History.

Will one day be enough to take in all the exhibits and attractions? How long does the average person spend there?
My capacity to take in the exhibits probably exceeds the average user.

If not, are there parts of the museum that are more popular than others, so I can prioritize some things over others?

Comment: If you're into science, any kind of natural science, "all day" is really easy to do. I did do all day, then another 3 hours the next day. If I'm in DC again ever, I'll plan a whole day then too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anywhere from several hours to all day and, as you're on the Mall, you can go in and out of all of the Smithsonian buildings there free of change.

> National Museum of Natural History: [Discover the Museum's Must-Sees](http://naturalhistory.si.edu/visit/)
>
> Tarantula feedings, the biggest blue diamond in the world, a Live Coral Reef... there is plenty for you to do at the world’s largest natural history museum! [Click here to learn more about the Museum's Must-sees](http://naturalhistory.si.edu/visit/mustsees.html).